# NFC 13.56MHz RF - Use inductor in place of pcb trace made antenna

Tags: antenna, inductor, pcb-antenna, nfc

I need to make a NFC antenna on NFC tranceiver->LC filter->matching circuit->antenna.

Inductance shows to be 1.5uH on an online calculator of nfc antennas. Can I simply just place a good inductor of 1.5uH instead drawing all the antenna? Will work from same distance?

Comment: I seriously doubt it.

Comment: It will not, think of the antenna like 1 half of a transformer, it needs to couple into the antenna in the RFID card to actually function.